# NSMutableArray Count

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I am reading through some code and I came across the following statement and it seems to make absolutely no sense.  The line is coded below.  It takes the first object of an NSMutableArray and then sends the "count" message.  What exactly is this doing?

```
for (int j = 0; j < [[inputData objectAtIndex:0] count]; j++)
//inputData is just an NSMutableArray
```

Could someone please explain this to me?  I have never come across this before.  I thought at first maybe it was like a 2-D array scenario where array[x].length is different from array.length, but inputData is just a single NSMutableArray of like 10 numbers.

Comment: Are you getting a runtime error? It's doing exactly what you said yourself, sending the `count` message to the first element of `inputData` and using the return value as the upper limit of the iteration.

Comment: It ran fine when I first compiled and ran it, but I did some slight modification (its from a school project) and now that line gives me an error and I don't know why.  I just don't see how you can "count" a NSNumber.

Comment: Right, NSNumber's don't respond to `count`. So when this was working before, I'm guessing this wasn't an array of NSNumber's.

Comment: Oh psh you're right.  It was an array of them.  Now it makes more sense on that end.  Haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your array(in this case `inpuData`) has a key-value matching mechanism, this loop will increment its index but since everytime the condition is the same(the count of `[inputData objectAtIndex:0]` will never change ) this will cause an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

If you are correct that `inputData` contains `NSNumber`s, then what happens is that the first time through, you get an exception because `NSNumber` does not respond to `-count`.

The only way that code would do anything else is if  `[inputData objectAtIndex:0]` responds to `-count`.  It can be any object that responds to `-count` not just an array.  Actually, it would also not throw an exception if `inputData` was `nil`.  The expression would then return 0 (sending `objectAtIndex:` to `nil` returns `nil` and sending `count` to `nil` returns 0).